# MIDI controller

Tags: midi

I recently bought a second hand midi controller (Alesis Q49) and I' m trying to connect it to my p/c, so that I can play (not interested in recording). I've installed 'virtual piano', selected my midi in MIDI Device menu, but still cannot hear sound from my midi.

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: All on the same MIDI channel?

Comment: Do you have a sound card?

Comment: Hi Tom, I do have sound card for my guitar recordings, can I use it for my midi ?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you've connected 'OUT' on the controller to 'IN' on your computer and your cable is not broken.
- Make sure that both devices are set to the same MIDI channel.
- Make sure that your software is sending audio to the correct audio output, and the volume is turned up.

Answer (score 0):

I use an old but still very useful free program for Windows called MIDI OX, which monitors and displays all sorts of MIDI messages going on between PC and controllers. http://www.midiox.com/

This software is extremely useful for figuring out what is going on. It'll show you if a device is connected or not, it'll show you events when pressing the keys or other buttons, and so on. Various filters allow to only see certain messages and not others, etc.

I'm sure there are other similar programs for Mac and Windows if you look. Google "MIDI monitor software" or something like that to find them.